# How to move popup window while user scroll window using gesture detector

Tags: android

I am placing a popup window while the user scrolls the window using gesture detector, but it's not updating to the correct position. 
Can anybody tell me how to do this? Can anybody tell me how to update the position?

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {


        if(e1.getX() > e2.getX())
        {
                window.update((int)e1.getX(), (int)e1.getY(), -1, -1);

        }
        else
        {
            window.update((int)e2.getX(), (int)e2.getY(), -1, -1);

        }
```

Comment: it will only go to the right?

Comment: @sherif yes it is going right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need the second MotionEvent Coordinates

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    window.update((int)e2.getX(), (int)e2.getY(), -1, -1);
}
```

Comment: while scrolling mypopupwindow is jolting how to avoid that?

Comment: maybe you should save previous x and previous y and move after certain threshold is passed